# Are smooth irreducible affine varieties set theoretical complete intersection?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, complete-intersection

I'm trying to prove a lemma, so I wanted to use the next claim (which I do not know if it is true or if there is a counter example): every smooth irreducible affine variety is set theoretical complete intersection. Or if this is not true I would like to know if there is a counter example to it.

I have tried to find a counter example or find the result in the literature, but I had no luck. I suspected that this fact is true, however, I was unable to prove it.

The lemma I want to prove using this plausible claim is:
Given a smooth irreducible variety $V$ of dimension $d$ with ideal $I(V) = (f_1,…,f_r)⊆k[x_1,…,x_n]$, we can construct the ideal $I ' (V) ⊆k[x_1,…,x_n,y_1,…,y_n]$ given by $I ′ (V) =(∇f_1⋅(y_1,…,y_n),…,∇f_r⋅(y_1,…y_n))$. Then every irreducible component $W$ of $Z(I ′ (V))$ such that $π(W)∩V≠∅$ has $dim(W)≥n+d$ where $π$ is the projection to the first $n$ coordinates

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Your conclusion can be proved “Zariski locally.”  Every smooth subvariety is Zariski locally a complete intersection.

Comment: All smooth curves in affine spaces are set- theoretic complete intersections. Higher dimensional varieties, this is an open question. The only general case known is when the conormal bundle is trivial, for example affine spaces embedded in higher dimensional affine spaces.

Comment: @Mohan : do you have a reference or a sketch of proof for your claim about affine smooth curves?

Comment: I think its a Theorem from Ferrand @Libli

Comment: @Libli For a curve in three space, this is a theorem of Ferrand ( and Szpiro). Higher dimensional case is due to me, Inv. Math., late seventies.